# HP DL360 vs DL160 Gen9

Tags: hardware, hp

What is the advantages of HP DL360p Gen9 comparing to HP DL160 Gen9? I need server for HFT trading, requirements are:

- Solarflare or Mellanox network card
- latency
- speed
- one Xeon E5-2690 v3 processor
- 2 power supply (not essential)

i don't care about:

- hard drive and speed of HDD
- virtualization
- throughput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy - the DL160 Gen9 doesn't support the 'one Xeon E5-2690 v3 processor' you require. In fact the 'best' it can do is an E5-2660v3.

Comment: i think i can live with one E5-2660v3, but Solarflare or Mellanox network cards are mandatory.

Comment: Good, they'll work just fine in either - but I really would advise dual PSUs.

Comment: how did you know that I can install `E5-2660v3` ?

Comment: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04375607

Answer (score 1):

Heh heh... you always ask [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/509198/hp-dl360p-gen8-for-low-latency-trading-what-to-upgrade) [about](https://serverfault.com/questions/508847/how-do-i-disable-processor-power-and-utilization-monitoring-on-an-hp-proliant) [trading](https://serverfault.com/questions/480441/hp-dl360-gen8-server-support-for-ddio) systems.

Use whatever you want with the right CPU spec for your application's needs. Optimize the OS/BIOS according to [HP's low-latency tuning parameters](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01804533.pdf) for your chosen operating system.

The DL360 will have more options available to you in this respect. In addition, there will be better monitoring and hardware resiliency features on the 300-series box versus the 100-series.

Comment: DL160 is not in the list of "recommended hardware". It would be interesting to know what exactly do I loose. I don't need many feautres, for example 16 GB of memory is enough for me, probably it doesn't make sense to pay for 360p Gen9.

Comment: Use the right hardware for the application.

Comment: and don't use wrong hardware for the application!